# Unable to SSH in to two Virtual Machines concurrently via NAT

Tags: networking, virtualization

please have mercy on me, I'm new to Ubuntu!

I have a server with a single IPv4 address running Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS.

This server is running two virtual machines (also running 16.04.2 LTS).
The virtual machines have 192.168.22.X IPs so I've routed port 22 on each virtual machine to ports 30000 and 30200 respectively.

I am able to access each virtual machine one at a time via SSH but I can't access them both concurrently.
Once I've opened a connection to the first VM, the second VM takes about 30 seconds to prompt for a password, once logged in, the terminal for VM1 has locked up.

I'm completely stuck!

Is there anything blindingly obvious I'm missing?

Comment: Not sure, but perhaps it has something to do with both VMs using the same physical network adapter (from host) if they are bridged. You may need a more complex setup.

Comment: I am using a bridged adapter. I have no problem connecting to the host server via SSH. I can connect to the host and one of the VM's. It's just an issue between the two VMs. @MichaelBay